Trying to reinitialize a JS library function but it fails with an error
I'm using this JS to generate a github activity chart. I can successfully load it up but I'm struggling to find a way to update the data after its first initialization:
var processedData = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
});


$('#activityMap').github_graph({
    data: processedData,
    texts: ['activity', 'activities']
});

This results in this chart:

And then I call get_activity() to load new activity from my database:
function get_activity() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "?handler=LoadActivity",
        success: function (data) {
            var activities = JSON.parse(data).activities;
            //updated activity
            processedData = processActivitiesData(activities);
            //I tried reinitializing here:
            $('#activityMap').github_graph({
                data: processedData,
                texts: ['activity', 'activities']
            });`
        },
        error: function (error) {

        }
    });
}

However that reinit doesnt work and results in:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).github_graph is not a function
Referring to how the library is structured, I can only guess that it can't be called as a normal function and reinit. Instead needs to be called on the top-level of the JS and can't be nested. How can I update the library's initialization to support this so that I can async call my new activity?
The library JS in reference:
/**
 * Jquery plugin to render like contribution graph on Github.
 *
 * @see       {@link https://github.com/bachvtuan/Github-Contribution-Graph}
 * @author    bachvtuan@gmail.com
 * @license   MIT License
 * @since     0.1.0
 */

//Format string
if (!String.prototype.formatString) {
  String.prototype.formatString = function () {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
      return typeof args[number] != "undefined" ? args[number] : match;
    });
  };
}

(function ($) {
  $.fn.github_graph = function (options) {
    //If the number less than 10, add Zero before it
    var prettyNumber = function (number) {
      return number < 10
        ? "0" + number.toString()
        : (number = number.toString());
    };

    /*
        Count the number on each day and store the object
        */
    var processListTimeStamp = function (list_timestamp) {
      //The result will store into this varriable
      obj_timestamp = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < list_timestamp.length; i++) {
        var _type = typeof list_timestamp[i];
        var _d =
          _type == "number"
            ? new Date(list_timestamp[i])
            : new Date(list_timestamp[i].timestamp);

        var display_date = getDisplayDate(_d);
        var increase = _type == "number" ? 1 : list_timestamp[i].count;
        if (!obj_timestamp[display_date]) {
          obj_timestamp[display_date] = increase;
        } else {
          obj_timestamp[display_date] += increase;
        }
      }
    };

    var getDisplayDate = function (date_obj) {
      var pretty_month = prettyNumber(date_obj.getMonth() + 1);
      var pretty_date = prettyNumber(date_obj.getDate());
      return "{0}-{1}-{2}".formatString(
        date_obj.getFullYear(),
        pretty_month,
        pretty_date,
      );
    };

    var getCount = function (display_date) {
      if (obj_timestamp[display_date]) {
        return obj_timestamp[display_date];
      }
      return 0;
    };

    var getColor = function (count) {
      if (typeof settings.colors[0] == "string") {
        return count > settings.colors.length - 1
          ? settings.colors[settings.colors.length - 1]
          : settings.colors[count];
      }

      const isLargeNumber = (element) => element.count > count;
      i = settings.colors.findIndex(isLargeNumber);
      return i == -1
        ? settings.colors[settings.colors.length - 1].color
        : settings.colors[i - 1].color;
    };

    var start = function () {
      processListTimeStamp(settings.data);
      var wrap_chart = _this;

      settings.colors_length = settings.colors.length;
      var radius = settings.border.radius;
      var hoverColor = settings.border.hover_color;
      var clickCallback = settings.click;

      var start_date;
      if (settings.start_date == null) {
        // if set null, will get from 365 days from now
        start_date = new Date();
        start_date.setMonth(start_date.getMonth() - 12);
        start_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() + 1);
      } else {
        // formats:
        // - YYYY-MM-DD
        // - YYYY/MM/DD
        start_date = new Date(settings.start_date);
      }

      end_date = new Date(start_date);
      end_date.setMonth(end_date.getMonth() + 12);
      end_date.setDate(end_date.getDate() - 1);

      var loop_html = "";
      var step = 13;

      var month_position = [];
      month_position.push({ month_index: start_date.getMonth(), x: 0 });
      var using_month = start_date.getMonth();

      var week = 0;
      var g_x = week * step;
      var item_html = '<g transform="translate(' + g_x.toString() + ', 0)">';

      for (
        ;
        start_date.getTime() <= end_date.getTime();
        start_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() + 1)
      ) {
        if (start_date.getDay() == 0) {
          var item_html =
            '<g transform="translate(' + g_x.toString() + ', 0)">';
        }

        var month_in_day = start_date.getMonth();
        var data_date = getDisplayDate(start_date);

        if (start_date.getDay() == 0 && month_in_day != using_month) {
          using_month = month_in_day;
          month_position.push({ month_index: using_month, x: g_x });
        }
        var count = getCount(data_date);
        var color = getColor(count);

        var y = start_date.getDay() * step;
        item_html +=
          '<rect class="day" width="11" height="11" y="' +
          y +
          '" fill="' +
          color +
          '" data-count="' +
          count +
          '" data-date="' +
          data_date +
          '" rx="' +
          radius +
          '" ry="' +
          radius +
          '"/>';

        if (start_date.getDay() == 6) {
          item_html += "</g>";
          loop_html += item_html;

          item_html = null;

          week++;
          g_x = week * step;
        }
      }

      if (item_html != null) {
        item_html += "</g>";
        loop_html += item_html;
      }

      //trick
      if (month_position[1].x - month_position[0].x < 40) {
        //Fix ugly graph by remove first item
        month_position.shift(0);
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < month_position.length; i++) {
        var item = month_position[i];
        var month_name = settings.month_names[item.month_index];
        loop_html +=
          '<text x="' +
          item.x +
          '" y="-5" class="month">' +
          month_name +
          "</text>";
      }

      //Add Monday, Wenesday, Friday label
      loop_html +=
        '<text text-anchor="middle" class="wday" dx="-10" dy="22">{0}</text>'.formatString(
          settings.h_days[0],
        ) +
        '<text text-anchor="middle" class="wday" dx="-10" dy="48">{0}</text>'.formatString(
          settings.h_days[1],
        ) +
        '<text text-anchor="middle" class="wday" dx="-10" dy="74">{0}</text>'.formatString(
          settings.h_days[2],
        );

      //Fixed size for now with width= 721 and height = 110
      var wire_html =
        '<svg width="721" height="110" viewBox="0 0 721 110"  class="js-calendar-graph-svg">' +
        '<g transform="translate(20, 20)">' +
        loop_html +
        "</g>" +
        "</svg>";

      wrap_chart.html(wire_html);

      $(_this)
        .find(".day")
        .on("click", function () {
          if (clickCallback) {
            clickCallback(
              $(this).attr("data-date"),
              parseInt($(this).attr("data-count")),
            );
          }
        });

      $(_this)
        .find(".day")
        .hover(
          function () {
            $(this).attr("style", "stroke-width: 1; stroke: " + hoverColor);
          },
          function () {
            $(this).attr("style", "stroke-width:0");
          },
        );

      _this.find("rect").on("mouseenter", mouseEnter);
      _this.find("rect").on("mouseleave", mouseLeave);
      appendTooltip();
    };

    var mouseLeave = function (evt) {
      $(".svg-tip").hide();
    };

    //handle event mouseenter when enter into rect element
    var mouseEnter = function (evt) {
      var target_offset = $(evt.target).offset();
      var count = $(evt.target).attr("data-count");
      var date = $(evt.target).attr("data-date");

      var count_text = count > 1 ? settings.texts[1] : settings.texts[0];
      var text = "{0} {1} on {2}".formatString(count, count_text, date);

      var svg_tip = $(".svg-tip").show();
      svg_tip.html(text);
      var svg_width = Math.round(svg_tip.width() / 2 + 5);
      var svg_height = svg_tip.height() * 2 + 10;

      svg_tip.css({ top: target_offset.top - svg_height - 5 });
      svg_tip.css({ left: target_offset.left - svg_width });
    };
    //Append tooltip to display when mouse enter the rect element
    //Default is display:none
    var appendTooltip = function () {
      if ($(".svg-tip").length == 0) {
        $("body").append(
          '<div class="svg-tip svg-tip-one-line" style="display:none" ></div>',
        );
      }
    };

    var settings = $.extend(
      {
        colors: ["#eeeeee", "#d6e685", "#8cc665", "#44a340", "#44a340"],
        //colors: ['#eeeeee', '#e68585', '#c66865', '#ff4742', '#ff4742'],
        border: {
          radius: 2,
          hover_color: "#999",
        },
        click: null,
        start_date: null,
        //List of name months
        month_names: [
          "Jan",
          "Feb",
          "Mar",
          "Apr",
          "May",
          "Jun",
          "Jul",
          "Aug",
          "Sep",
          "Oct",
          "Nov",
          "Dec",
        ],
        h_days: ["M", "W", "F"],
        //Default is empty, it can be overrided
        data: [],
      },
      options,
    );

    var _this = $(this);

    start();
  };
})(jQuery);

I call get_activity from:
$(document).ready(function () {
   get_activity();
});


This will occur if you have 2x script src=jquery.js.  The first one works but when it calls it later, jquery has been reloaded and the new jquery doesn't include the plugin.  Check your source very closely (probably easiest in browser with view-source).  At the bottom, there's probably a second jquery.js.   This can happen if you're using a framework such as MVC which has jquery in the layout or wordpress which has its own jquery and you add a new one before it.

@fdomn-m you were right! I had two jquery scripts being loaded! Thank you :)

You do not show the important stuff like WHEN do you call your get_activity
You can simplify this much more to make sure you have all you need at the time you need it:
$(() => {
  $.getJSON("?handler=LoadActivity", (data) => {
    $('#activityMap').github_graph({
      data: processActivitiesData(data.activities),
      texts: ['activity', 'activities']
    });
  });
});

The function can be called as often as you want


const getData = () => {
  const data = ({  activities: getActivity(240, 2) }); // mocking an array of timestamps minimum 2 days apart
  //  $.getJSON("?handler=LoadActivity", (data) => {
  $('#activityMap').github_graph({
    data: data.activities,  
    texts: ['activity', 'activities']
  });
  //  });
};

$(() => {
  getData();
  setInterval(getData,3000)
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="activityMap"></div>

<script>
// testing code

const msPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // milliseconds in a day
const today = new Date();
const startTimestamp = new Date(today.getFullYear() - 1, today.getMonth(), today.getDate()).getTime(); // last year, same month
const getActivity = (n, m) => {
  let lastTimestamp = startTimestamp;
  return Array.from({ length: n }).map(() => {
    const daysToAdd = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * m);
    lastTimestamp += daysToAdd * msPerDay;
    return {
      timestamp: lastTimestamp,
      count: daysToAdd
    }
  })
  return Array.from(timestamps);
};


/**
 * Jquery plugin to render like contribution graph on Github.
 *
 * @see       {@link https://github.com/bachvtuan/Github-Contribution-Graph}
 * @author    bachvtuan@gmail.com
 * @license   MIT License
 * @since     0.1.0
 */

//Format string
if (!String.prototype.formatString) {
  String.prototype.formatString = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) {
      return typeof args[number] != 'undefined' ?
        args[number] :
        match;
    });
  };
}

(function($) {



  $.fn.github_graph = function(options) {

    //If the number less than 10, add Zero before it
    var prettyNumber = function(number) {
      return number < 10 ? '0' + number.toString() : number = number.toString();
    };

    /*
    Count the number on each day and store the object
    */
    var processListTimeStamp = function(list_timestamp) {

      //The result will store into this varriable
      obj_timestamp = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < list_timestamp.length; i++) {
        var _type = typeof(list_timestamp[i]);
        var _d = _type == "number" ? new Date(list_timestamp[i]) : new Date(list_timestamp[i].timestamp)

        var display_date = getDisplayDate(_d);
        var increase = _type == "number" ? 1 : list_timestamp[i].count;
        if (!obj_timestamp[display_date]) {
          obj_timestamp[display_date] = increase;
        } else {
          obj_timestamp[display_date] += increase;
        }
      }
    }

    var getDisplayDate = function(date_obj) {
      var pretty_month = prettyNumber(date_obj.getMonth() + 1);
      var pretty_date = prettyNumber(date_obj.getDate());
      return "{0}-{1}-{2}".formatString(date_obj.getFullYear(), pretty_month, pretty_date);
    }

    var getCount = function(display_date) {
      if (obj_timestamp[display_date]) {
        return obj_timestamp[display_date];
      }
      return 0;
    }

    var getColor = function(count) {
      if (typeof(settings.colors[0]) == "string") {
        return count > settings.colors.length - 1 ? settings.colors[settings.colors.length - 1] : settings.colors[count];
      }

      const isLargeNumber = (element) => element.count > count;
      i = settings.colors.findIndex(isLargeNumber);
      return i == -1 ? settings.colors[settings.colors.length - 1].color : settings.colors[i - 1].color;
    }

    var start = function() {
      processListTimeStamp(settings.data);
      var wrap_chart = _this;

      settings.colors_length = settings.colors.length;
      var radius = settings.border.radius;
      var hoverColor = settings.border.hover_color;
      var clickCallback = settings.click;



      var start_date;
      if (settings.start_date == null) {
        // if set null, will get from 365 days from now
        start_date = new Date();
        start_date.setMonth(start_date.getMonth() - 12);
        start_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() + 1)
      } else {
        // formats:
        // - YYYY-MM-DD
        // - YYYY/MM/DD
        start_date = new Date(settings.start_date);
      }

      end_date = new Date(start_date);
      end_date.setMonth(end_date.getMonth() + 12);
      end_date.setDate(end_date.getDate() - 1);

      var loop_html = "";
      var step = 13;

      var month_position = [];
      month_position.push({
        month_index: start_date.getMonth(),
        x: 0
      });
      var using_month = start_date.getMonth();


      var week = 0;
      var g_x = week * step;
      var item_html = '<g transform="translate(' + g_x.toString() + ', 0)">';

      for (; start_date.getTime() <= end_date.getTime(); start_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() + 1)) {

        if (start_date.getDay() == 0) {
          var item_html = '<g transform="translate(' + g_x.toString() + ', 0)">';
        }

        var month_in_day = start_date.getMonth();
        var data_date = getDisplayDate(start_date);

        if (start_date.getDay() == 0 && month_in_day != using_month) {
          using_month = month_in_day;
          month_position.push({
            month_index: using_month,
            x: g_x
          });
        }
        var count = getCount(data_date);
        var color = getColor(count);

        var y = start_date.getDay() * step;
        item_html += '<rect class="day" width="11" height="11" y="' + y + '" fill="' + color + '" data-count="' + count + '" data-date="' + data_date + '" rx="' + radius + '" ry="' + radius + '"/>';

        if (start_date.getDay() == 6) {
          item_html += "</g>";
          loop_html += item_html;

          item_html = null;

          week++;
          g_x = week * step;
        }
      }

      if (item_html != null) {
        item_html += "</g>";
        loop_html += item_html;
      }


      //trick
      if (month_position[1].x - month_position[0].x < 40) {
        //Fix ugly graph by remove first item
        month_position.shift(0);
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < month_position.length; i++) {
        var item = month_position[i];
        var month_name = settings.month_names[item.month_index];
        loop_html += '<text x="' + item.x + '" y="-5" class="month">' + month_name + '</text>';
      }

      //Add Monday, Wenesday, Friday label
      loop_html += '<text text-anchor="middle" class="wday" dx="-10" dy="22">{0}</text>'.formatString(settings.h_days[0]) +
        '<text text-anchor="middle" class="wday" dx="-10" dy="48">{0}</text>'.formatString(settings.h_days[1]) +
        '<text text-anchor="middle" class="wday" dx="-10" dy="74">{0}</text>'.formatString(settings.h_days[2]);

      //Fixed size for now with width= 721 and height = 110
      var wire_html =
        '<svg width="721" height="110" viewBox="0 0 721 110"  class="js-calendar-graph-svg">' +
        '<g transform="translate(20, 20)">' +
        loop_html +
        '</g>' +
        '</svg>';

      wrap_chart.html(wire_html);

      $(_this).find(".day").on('click', function() {

        if (clickCallback) {
          clickCallback($(this).attr("data-date"), parseInt($(this).attr("data-count")));
        }

      });

      $(_this).find(".day").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("style", "stroke-width: 1; stroke: " + hoverColor);
      }, function() {
        $(this).attr("style", "stroke-width:0");
      });

      _this.find('rect').on("mouseenter", mouseEnter);
      _this.find('rect').on("mouseleave", mouseLeave);
      appendTooltip();

    }

    var mouseLeave = function(evt) {
      $('.svg-tip').hide();
    }

    //handle event mouseenter when enter into rect element
    var mouseEnter = function(evt) {

      var target_offset = $(evt.target).offset();
      var count = $(evt.target).attr('data-count');
      var date = $(evt.target).attr('data-date');

      var count_text = (count > 1) ? settings.texts[1] : settings.texts[0];
      var text = "{0} {1} on {2}".formatString(count, count_text, date);

      var svg_tip = $('.svg-tip').show();
      svg_tip.html(text);
      var svg_width = Math.round(svg_tip.width() / 2 + 5);
      var svg_height = svg_tip.height() * 2 + 10;

      svg_tip.css({
        top: target_offset.top - svg_height - 5
      });
      svg_tip.css({
        left: target_offset.left - svg_width
      });
    }
    //Append tooltip to display when mouse enter the rect element
    //Default is display:none
    var appendTooltip = function() {
      if ($('.svg-tip').length == 0) {
        $('body').append('<div class="svg-tip svg-tip-one-line" style="display:none" ></div>');
      }
    }

    var settings = $.extend({
      colors: ['#eeeeee', '#d6e685', '#8cc665', '#44a340', '#44a340'],
      border: {
        radius: 2,
        hover_color: "#999"
      },
      click: null,
      start_date: null,
      //List of name months
      month_names: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
      h_days: ['M', 'W', 'F'],
      //Default is empty, it can be overrided
      data: [],
    }, options);

    var _this = $(this);

    start();

  };

}(jQuery));</script>




Updated the code! I call that from $(document).ready(function () {

I actually tried initializing this after I got the data from the get_activity function but it results int he same error above. It doesn't like when I call that from within another function for some reason

We need to see more details. If $('#activityMap').github_graph({     data: [],     texts: ['activity', 'activities'] }); works, then $('#activityMap').github_graph({     data: processActivitiesData(data.activities),     texts: ['activity', 'activities'] }); also should work

Surprisingly thats all the code. The 2nd time I call that it causes that error. It only allows me to call it outside of functions on top level

There is nothing special needed to call this more than once. See my updated code with a mock of your activities
